# Kotlin replace Regex but keep matching case

Tags: regex, kotlin, replace

I have an app that is doing transcriptions and with the resulting text I'm doing several replacements of expected typos from the transcribing service. But there may be cases where the replacement should be case sensitive to the expected typo, such as if the word is at the beginning of a sentence. For example:

```kotlin
fun replaceText (aText: String): String = aText.
   replace ("""\b[gG]onna\b""".toRegex(), "going to")
```

Ideally if it found "gonna" it would replace it with "going to" and if it found "Gonna" it would replace it with "Going to"

("gonna" is probably not going to be at the start of a sentence but just using it as an example)

I know that I could just duplicate the function by doing a regex to check for lowercase and replace with lowercase and then another replace that checks for uppercase and replace with uppercase, but is there a way to do this replacement with the matching case?

Comment: Perhaps this can be solved by relying on the knowledge of [Capitalization Rules in English](https://www.scribbr.com/language-rules/capitalization-rules), rather than Regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use grouping first letter `G` or `g`, then replace with matched group.

```
fun replaceText (aText: String): String = aText.
   replace ("""\b([gG])onna\b""".toRegex(), "$1oing to")
```

See regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/DcFgdy/1)